# Migrating Visual Studio solutions (page.aspx) from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-on-prem, visual-studio-2012, solution-deployment, migrationapi

I have several visual studio page.aspx solutions that I want to migrate from SharePoint 2013 Onprem to SharePoint Online. How do I go about it?

Comment: What kind of solutions are they? Depending on the solution there will be different suitable approaches...

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate more on what type of solution you have - in general we cannot migrate or deploy the custom visual studio solution to SharePoint online, we need re-develop the solution using the modern technology SharePoint Framework (SPFx).